# Assembly x8086 getting chars till 'z' or 'Z' and print small chars,big chars,numbers

Tags: assembly, tasm, emu8086

I have questions:

1. Program to get input from user till 'z' or 'Z' is inputted
   the program will check for the chars, and print
   (new line) small chars
   (new line) big chars
   (new line) numbers
   [without 'z' or 'Z']
   can't use variables.
   only Stack.
   example :
   input: ASdf154sdgdf123vcvbz
   Small chars: dfsdgdfvcvb
   Big chars: AS
   Numbers: 154123
2. Program with string size Define N, program will take input from the user, and will take only numbers from the input and put them to string with N size, the input size is N. and print message with the string (must have only numbers from input) and amount of the numbers.
   example (string size 10)
   input : 1adr1t23g7
   string: 11237
   print out:
   The String of numbers are : 11237 and Tolat Numbers are : 5

Stuck with question 1, not understand the subject and cant continue to question 2.
thanks to every one who may help me

This is code for question 1:

```
STA SEGMENT STACK
    DB 100H DUP (0)
STA ENDS
CODE SEGMENT
    ASSUME CS:CODE,SS:STA
MAIN:
    MOV BP, SP
    MOV BX, BP
    SUB BP, 2
    MOV CX, 0
INPUT:
    MOV AH, 01H
    INT 21H
    INC CX
    CMP AL, 'z'
    JE TOPRINT
    CMP AL, 'Z'
    JE TOPRINT
    MOV AH, 0
    PUSH AX
    MOV AX, 0
    JNE INPUT
    MOV DI, CX
TOPRINT:
    POP DX
    CMP DX, 'a'
    JL NEXT
    CMP DX, 'z'
    JG NEXT
    MOV AH, 02H
    INT 21H
    CMP DX, 'A'
    JL NEXT
    CMP DX, 'Z'
    JG NEXT
    MOV AH, 02H
    INT 21H
    CMP DX, '0'
    JL NEXT
    CMP DX, '9'
    JG NEXT
    MOV AH, 02H
    INT 21H
NEXT:
    SUB BP, 2
    DEC CX
    CMP CX, 0
    JMP TOPRINT
    MOV AX, 4C00H
    INT 21H
CODE ENDS
    END MAIN
```

Comment: "can't use variables." - that's actually not an issue in assembly, as there are no *variables* at all... ... jokes aside (well, it's not joke, it's just sad misconception used by your lectors, but funny one ... at least now I know where this nonsense may come from): what is your question? The code was written by you? Does it work? If not, what it does? Did you check with debugger, what it does, and how that differs from what you want?

Comment: just by reading your code.. if you start it, and enter "z" immediately, it will do `pop dx` even if there was no `push ...` before. I guess that's one of your bugs, and not intentional. I guess such bug should be easy to spot in debugger, so maybe try this scenario in debugger few times, until you are comfortable enough and feel like you would spot that bug without my external input in comment... Then look for other problems...

Answer (score 1):

well it seems the task is designed to exercise the stack usage, and your comment:

> not understand the subject

seems to be accurate. But then you are asking people to write short chapter of book into simple SO answer... hmm, usually I don't like to do that, because full book is full book, and short answer will have to omit some details, but let's try if something cut down can hold as answer:

The stack memory in 16b real mode is ordinary computer memory, but the register pair `ss:sp` points at "top of the stack", and there are several instructions implicitly using these two registers to access memory, like `pop dx` does "read word value at memory address `ss:sp` into register `dx`, then add 2 to `sp` (to make it point to next word in memory)" (word in sense "16 bits of information", not "text" word).

Take a note of push/pop instruction descriptions (check instruction guide, either official docs from Intel or for basics something like https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ will do), the `push` does subtract from `sp`, i.e. the stack "grows" from high memory addresses toward low memory addresses, and when you `pop`, the `sp` goes back toward high memory addresses. The "top of the stack" is last item pushed into it, which is on current address `ss:sp`. The previous item pushed to stack is at `ss:sp+2` (in 16b mode), etc... so if you want to use `bp` for addressing, and you copy value of `sp` into `bp` after last `push` storing items into stack, then your items are accessible by using `[bp+0], [bp+2], [bp+4], ...` addressing (note: `bp` is by default associating with `ss` segment, so `mov ax,[bp]` is implicit `mov ax,ss:[bp]` (does load value from stack segment), while `mov ax,[bx]` is by default implicitly `mov ax,ds:[bx]` (does load from data segment).. unless you explicitly specify different segment override in source code).

Pay also attention to instructions `call` and `ret`, these are implicitly using stack too, so would you start to use subroutines by using `call`/`ret` instructions, the structure of stack data will contain also return-address when inside subroutine (at "top of the stack" when entering subroutine).

In your code in the emu8086 you are reserving the memory area for stack by defining the stack segment at beginning of your code, reserving 256 bytes (128 words), which is quite minimal stack for such stack-heavy task, as your code will eat stack at pace "one word per one input char", you can enter 128 chars at most... that may seem reasonable, until you learn that the actual user stack is used also by DOS interrupts, which has two major consequences:

- some of those 128 words are used by interrupts (not sure how much, let's say 30 words), and if you enter 100 characters, the interrupts will go below your reserved memory already, starting to overwrite parts of memory you didn't reserve for it ("stack overflow" issue)
- the memory below **current** `ss:sp` is periodically being overwritten by DOS interrupt handlers

Your task sounds like you can do:

- read user input in a loop until z/Z is entered, putting every item into stack (and counting = you have now something like that, once you fix to `pop` only correct amount of times), or having "end" pointer of empty stack)
- go through all inputted values, and output only small chars
- output newline
- go through all inputted values, and output only capital chars
- output newline
- go through all inputted values, and output only numbers
- output newline
- exit

Now you may be tempted to do `pop` in the very first "go through all inputted values", but that means you would move the `ss:sp` up toward the original "empty stack" ... and if you would then subtract 2*items from `sp`, you may think you can now `pop` the same chars again from the memory, cheating by the `sp` modification. But if some interrupt did happen meanwhile, the original chars below `ss:sp` at that moment are destroyed, so do NOT `pop` for the first two loops.

use rather `bp` to access data, i.e. `mov bp,sp` ahead of each output loop, and then loop items-many times doing `mov dl,[bp]` `add bp,2`, but keep the `ss:sp` unchanged (and keep copy of items amount somewhere, so you have it for second and third loop... or copy "empty" `sp` somewhere like `mov di,sp` at beginning, to do `cmp bp,di` to check in output loops, if you did read through all items.

If you are even less into the assembly programming subject, and you feel lost by most of my text, read some book or tutorial first.. the basics about registers/memory/etc can be often picked from this summary http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html which is targetting 32 bit mode, but I don't know about such short intro for 16b (I guess your lectors gave you some recommendations, what to study), or use google... keep in mind 16b mode is more tricky and difficult than 32b mode, because you have also to learn about memory segments, and the memory addressing is lot more constrained (`mov al,[cx]` does not exist in 16b mode, while `mov al,[ecx]` is legal in 32b mode).

If you have problem with just some particular part, ask in comments.

Then take a look in your code, learn to use debugger (it's absolutely essential, using stackoverflow web as debugging service is less efficient and considered by many (including me) as rude and bad behaviour ... if you can show that you did debug the code and you can describe the puzzling behaviour well (what is happening and what you did want/expect instead), there will be lot more people willing to write you answer, why that is happening and where your thinking process is wrong), and try to use the information above to rewrite it.